# Changing the kendo numeric filter format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am applying custom paging and sorting in the kendo grid. For one of my column I am getting a numeric text box. When I insert the value in numeric text box it is integer, but as the focus is removed from the filter numeric text box it converts into decimal. For eg: if I entered 32, it remains 32,but as the focus is removed the value becomes 32.00. But I want that value to remains 32.

So any one can please help me out with the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set like below

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Property).Filterable(x => x.UI("NumericFilter"));

<script type="text/javascript">
function NumericFilter(control) {
    $(control).kendoNumericTextBox({ "format": "n0", "decimals": 0 });

}
</script>
```

**Or 
use extension method**

```
columns.NumericColumn(x => x.Property);

public static GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel> NumericColumn<TModel, TValue>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> Column, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> Expression) where TModel : class
{
    return Column.Bound(Expression).Filterable(x => x.UI("NumericFilter"));

}
```

Comment: I have tried a lot, but I havent got lambda expression in Filterable field"Filterable(x => x.UI("NumericFilter"));". Do we need to add some js or something?

Comment: I think no. I am using Kendo MVC 2013.2.716.340
Also verify your web.config have the below line

<system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
<system.web>

Comment: I have this seting i web config. But the version I am using is : 2012.2.913.340. So may be this is the reason why I am not getting the lambda expression.

Comment: This solution works great but still inserts separator commas when the numeric text boxes lose focus.  See the solution below by @Kamran to fix that as well.

Comment: Thanks Working Fine :). For Extension method please use "using System.Linq.Expressions;" Namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and columns.Bound(x => x.Property).Filterable(x => x.UI("numericFilter")); was not working for me. Piggy backing off of Xavier John's answer I used columns.filterable.cell.template to fix my problem because telerik's documentation states:

> columns.filterable.ui String |Function
>
> The role data attribute of the widget used in the filter menu or a JavaScript function which initializes that widget.
>
> > This feature is not supported for columns which have their values option set.
> >     If filterable.mode is set to 'row', columns.filterable.cell.template should be used to customize the input.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.ui

Here's my code

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UnsoldStockBO.USS_STOCK>()
        .Name("searchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.CyAbbrev);
            columns.Bound(c => c.UssCrop).Filterable(filter => filter.Cell(c => c.Template("IntegerFilter")));
            columns.Bound(c => c.TtAbbrev);
            columns.Bound(c => c.PtAbbrev);
            columns.Bound(c => c.UssInternalGrade);
            columns.Bound(c => c.SuggestedPrice).Format("{0:c2}").Filterable(filter => filter.Cell(c => c.Template("NumericFilter")));
            columns.Bound(c => c.UssCtPricePerKilo).ClientTemplate("#:kendo.toString(UssCtPricePerKilo, 'c', Culture)#").Filterable(filter => filter.Cell(c => c.Template("NumericFilter")));
            columns.Bound(c => c.UssNetKilos).Format("{0:n}").Filterable(filter => filter.Cell(c => c.Template("NumericFilter")));
            columns.Bound(c => c.UssWriteDownCount).Format("{0:n0}").Filterable(filter => filter.Cell(c => c.Template("IntegerFilter")));
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Quick Edit" });
                command.Custom("EditStock").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" });
                command.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Delete" });
            }).HtmlAttributes(new { @nowrap = "nowrap" });
        })
        .Mobile()
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text("Add Stock").Action("Create", "Stock").Name("AddStock"))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("This record will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?"))
            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable()
            .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound").Cancel("onCancel"))
        .NoRecords("No records found.")
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .WebApi()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .PageSize(30)
                        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").Sync("sync_handler"))
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.UssId);
                        model.Field(c => c.CyAbbrev).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(c => c.UssCrop).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(c => c.TtAbbrev).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(c => c.PtAbbrev).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(c => c.UssInternalGrade).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(c => c.SuggestedPrice).Editable(false);
                    })
                    .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "webapi", action = "UnsoldStock_Get", userId = ((UnsoldStockBO.PSI_USER)Session["USS_User"]).UUid })))
                                .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "webapi", action = "UnsoldStock_Update", userName = ((UnsoldStockBO.PSI_USER)Session["USS_User"]).UUserName })).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "webapi", action = "UnsoldStock_Delete", id = "{0}", userName = ((UnsoldStockBO.PSI_USER)Session["USS_User"]).UUserName })).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))

                )
    )

<script type="text/javascript">

    function IntegerFilter(args) {
        args.element.kendoNumericTextBox({ format: "#", decimals: 0, spinners: false });
    }

    function NumericFilter(args) {
        args.element.kendoNumericTextBox({ spinners: false });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the filter column as

```js
column.filterable = {
    ui: numberFilter,
    cell: {
        template: numberFilter,
    }
};

function numberFilter(args) {
    var element = args instanceof jQuery ? args : args.element;
    element.kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "n0"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What *Palani Kumar* has said still inserts separators, that is it converts 12345 to 12,345; so i recommend the following edited code in case you want pure numbers without any formatting (no separators, no decimal points etc.).

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Property).Filterable(x => x.UI("numericFilter"));

<script type="text/javascript">
    function numericFilter(control) {
        $(control).kendoNumericTextBox({ format: "#", decimals: 0 });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set format on the filterable on the column like this:

```
            field: "TaskId",
            title: "TaskId",
            width: 80,
            filterable: {
                ui: function (element) {
                    element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                        format: "n0"
                    });
                }
            }
```

**Update**
This is the javascript version. here my complete grid defintion:

```
      $("#uxRunningTasksGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: runningTasksDataSource,
        height: $(document).height() - 280,
        autoBind: true,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: false,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columns: [{
            command: { text: "Details", click: openDetails }, title: " ", width: 80
        },
            {
                field: "TaskId",
                title: "TaskId",
                width: 80,
                filterable: {
                    ui: function (element) {
                        element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                            format: "n0"
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net core grid:
`columns.Bound(c => c.Expenditure).Format("{0:#,###.00}").Width(75);`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in Kendo UI Filter and it was not working for me.
i.e.:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ColumnName).Filterable(x => x.UI("numericFilter"));
```

But you can try this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model =>
{
    model.Id(p => p.ColumnID);       
    model.Field("ColumnName", typeof(string));

})
.PageSize(20)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the column format:

```
c.Bound(x => x.ColumnName).Format("{0:#}");
```

Comment: This didn,t worked as this set the format for the data being displayed in the column but, I data displayed in filter to be in the non decimal format.

Answer (score -1):

On Kendo NumericTextBox, Format is used to format the content of the input when it's not focused.
You have tu use Decimals du format the input when it's focused.
For example here is a NumericTextbox (asp.net) showing always integer :

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
        .Name("Total")
        .Format("n0")
        .Decimals(0)
    )
```

Hope it will help someone.